# "Terminating app due to uncaught exception" on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have one `for` loop in my code.
When execution of this for loop continues, my application crashes and prints the following message on the console:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:] index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'  Call stack at first throw:
```

Using this `for` loop I am trying to fill up a `NSMutableArray` but this is not what is being done.

Comment: cam you post the function where this crash happens?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Usually this happens when you try to access an element at an index outside of the bounds of the `NSArray`.

So say you had an `NSArray` like this:

```
NSArray *a = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"c", nil];
```

This code would print "Array index out of bounds" because bounds are 0 - 2:

```
@try {
   NSString *string = [a objectAtIndex:3];
} @catch(NSRangeException *e) {
   NSLog(@"Array index out of bounds");
}
```

The best way to solve this issue is to use **fast enumeration**:

```
for(id obj in array) {
   //do something with obj
}
```

Fast enumeration uses the enumerable object's implementation of the `NSFastEnumeration` protocol to handle all of the dirty work for you.

One thing that will usually cause this problem even while using fast enumeration is if you are enumerating a mutable structure such as an `NSMutableArray` and inside the body of the loop, you mutate the structure by using `removeObject:` or its variants, you will run into this exception sooner than later because the length of the structure is cached and therefore it will carry on to the next iteration even if it goes out of bounds.

But, using fast enumeration, you will catch this error rather quickly because the internal `__NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler` will catch it and throw up the following exception:

```
2011-02-11 00:30:49.825 MutableNSFastEnumerationTest[10547:a0f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <NSCFArray: 0x10010c960> was mutated while being enumerated.<CFArray 0x10010c960 [0x7fff70c45ee0]>{type = mutable-small, count = 2, values = (
    0 : <CFString 0x100001078 [0x7fff70c45ee0]>{contents = "b"}
    1 : <CFString 0x100001058 [0x7fff70c45ee0]>{contents = "c"}
)}'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8621e7b4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff80daa0f3 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff862765bf __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 303
    3   MutableNSFastEnumerationTest        0x0000000100000de7 main + 295
    4   MutableNSFastEnumerationTest        0x0000000100000cb8 start + 52
    5   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: Actually, your last example for removing objects would be skipping indexes because you are both incrementing `i` and also shifting the array left. So you'd be removing index 0, then 2, then 4, etc.

Comment: @TimGostony Wow good catch! Removed those rather unneeded examples. Thanks!

Comment: Also, a nice way to enumerate and modify the array without using indices is: `for(Object *something in [myMutableArr copy]){  /* ... */  [myMutableArr removeObject:something];  }`

Comment: Sure, it requires a copy, but for most use cases (n < 10000) the impact on performance is negligible. It also is a lot safer to not worry about index math. When it comes to apps, if the choice is "run 5ns faster" or "less likely to crash" I prefer the latter

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is implying that you are trying to access something out of range in your array (index 2 beyond bounds).  If you just have to access the array, your best bet is to use fast enumeration (for each loop).

```
for (NSString *str in array)
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

Something like this would protect from any index out of bounds exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The type of exception is called index out of bound exception.This is generally happen when you try to access an element of array which is not present.